# Sorting elements in perl structure n x n

Tags: perl, knn

I need to find the next neighbor using the euklid-distance-algorithm.

Given are two hashes with each 100 elements in this format:

```
$hash{$i}{price}
$hash{$i}{height}
```

I need to compare each hash elements with each other so that my result is a 100 x 100 matrix.

After that my matrix shoul be sorted after the following rules:

```
$hash{$i,$j}  {lowest_euklid_distance}
$hash{$i,$j+1}{lowest_euklid_distance + 1}
$hash{$i,$j+2}{lowest_euklid_distance + 2}
.
.
$hash{$i+1,$j}{lowest_euklid_distance}
$hash{$i+1,$j}{lowest_euklid_distance + 2}
.
.
$hash{$i+n,$j+n}{lowest_euklid_distance+n}
```

My problem is to sort these elements properly. 
Any adivices?

Thanks in advance.

/edit: adding more information:

I create the distance with the following subroutine:

```
sub euklid_distance{
    #w1 = price_testdata
    #w2 = height_testdata
    #h1 = price_origindata
    #h2 = height_origindata

    my $w1 = trim($_[0]);
    my $w2 = trim($_[1]);
    my $h1 = trim($_[2]);
    my $h2 = trim($_[3]);

    my $result = (((($w2-$w1)**2)+(($h2-$h1)**2))**(1/2));
    return $result;     
    }
```

I fetch the test and the origindata from two seperate lists.

The resulthash with the 100x100 matrix is created by the following code:

```
 my %distancehash;
 my $countvar=0;

for (my $j=0;$j<100;$j++){
    for (my $i=0;$i<100;$i++){
      $distancehash{$countvar}{distance}      = euklid_distance( $origindata{$i}{price}, $testdata{$j}{price}, $origindata{$i}{height}, $testdata{$j}{height} );
      $distancehash{$countvar}{originPrice}   = $origindata{$i}{price};
      $distancehash{$countvar}{originHeight}  = $origindata{$i}{height};
      $distancehash{$countvar}{testPrice}     = $testdata{$j}{price};
      $distancehash{$countvar}{testHeight}    = $testdata{$j}{height};
      $countvar++;
     }
    }
```

where $j goes over the testdata and $i over the origindata.

My goal is to have a new hash which is sorted by the lowest distance from the current $j ascending to the highest.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and provide some actual example data?

Comment: Added some code.

Comment: That wasn't the request. Sample input, and the corresponding output, please. And you gotta tag us (e.g. `@ikegami`) for us to see the reply.

Comment: For sorting the data that has already been processed, it is not relevant how it was calculated. The `$countvar` on the other hand is. In your second code block you show `$i,$j+1` as one of the keys in the data structure, but `$countvar` in the actual code is a simple iterator. A structure like `$foo->[$i]->[$j]` makes a lot more sense as an intermediate step, as it resembles the actual matrix you are building. If you want to condense it directly, you probably want to pick a key that contains both values, like `$i_$j`.